# rails 3 built-in rake tasks, where are they located?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake-task

I can put my custom rake tasks in `lib/tasks/`, but where are the built-in ones (i.e. db:migrate, db:seed, etc) stored?

I looked in: `[INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY]/gems/rails-[VERSION]/lib/tasks` but couldn't find that path.  Maybe it matters that I'm using RVM?

I'd like to inspect their source for some inspiration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at [/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake) for the database related rake tasks. All the other rake tasks are also present in *.rake files, so you can run a `find . -name "*.rake"` in the gems directory to find others.